# Why does this code sometimes not run when refreshing the page?

Tags: javascript

I have a page loading element which displays during the pageload and is then removed.  Most of the time, this works, but sometimes it doesn't so the user is left staring at the loader forever.

It usually works, but sometimes it doesn't when refreshing the page.  In Chrome, if I open developer tools, then it does always work fine.

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function (event) {
    console.log("removing loader");
    $('.preloader').fadeOut(500, function () { $('.preloader').remove(); });
});

window.addEventListener('load', function (event) {
    console.log("removing loader");
    $('.preloader').fadeOut(500, function () { $('.preloader').remove(); });
});
```

This code is in a js file, and I think what happens is that the file is cached, so it doesn't run again during the refresh.  Does the sound correct? Should I just put this in a script tag to ensure it always runs?

I put the code in both events as I was having issues with it sometimes not running. However, maybe this is not actually necessary.

Comment: You should put it on `window.load` if you want it run when all (synchronously loaded) resources (styles, scripts, images, media files) have finished loading. When your page looks good. And you should place it on `DOMContentLoaded` if you want your script to run when DOM parser reached `</html>` tag. If your script depends on element sizes, or should be ran when your DOM has been rendered, use first. If it simply computes or maybe loads some more async resources, run it on second.

Comment: Even if the file is cached, the code is still executed. It's the absolute same if you place it in a `<script>` tag. If it doesn't execute each time, the cause is elsewhere and you haven't showed anything suspect so far. Placing your script on `window.load` event should run it every single time. Unless your `.preloader` gets added to DOM ***after*** `window.load` is triggered. Is that possible?

Comment: did you use attribute= **async** or **defer**  for your script?

Comment: @Sphinx, No, but interesting thought

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu, thanks.  After moving the code to the top of the file and only use Load. it is working every time now. If you want to post something as an answer, I will accept.

Comment: I'm glad I could help. I'm not going to answer it. It's an often duplicate but comes in many forms. Most people ask about their jQuery aliases: `$(document).ready()` and `$(window).load()`. DOM manipulation and async loading goes on document. Visuals go on window (although this is not always true, especially for very performant websites - this one depends). But it's easier to remember like this. Happy coding!

Comment: And I couldn't answer it anyway because we haven't figured out why it didn't run. I could only answer if I understood the reason (and I'd probably need to be able to reproduce to make sure).

Comment: It could be that the document has already been loaded at the point that the script runs, in which case the handler that was just attached won't fire

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there are any errors during the loading of elements, some listeners can fail to trigger. Have to tried the simple,

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    console.log("removing loader");
    $('.preloader').fadeOut(500, function () { $('.preloader').remove(); });
});
```